# Option clash for package hyperref while Compiling in TexLive for arXiv submittal

Tags: errors, hyperref, arxiv

I am getting the option clash error and I can't seem to figure out why.  Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb} %for \mathbb{}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for underbrace annotations
\usepackage{mathtools} % for underbrace annotations
\usepackage{enumitem} % for command "\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]"
\usepackage{color} % for command "{\color{blue} TXTTXTTXT}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % for command \uwave{TXTTXT}
\usepackage{float} % for \begin{figure}[H]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pseudocode}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
%\bibliography{Refs}
%\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\usepackage{lipsum}       % for sample text
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{pstricks-add} % for crazy drawings
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! After appending the instructions `\begin{document}`, "`Hello World`", and `\end{document}` to your code in order to make it compilable, I am unable to generate any option clash-type errors. Please make your code fully compilable while generating the error you mention above.

Comment: Ok.  Here is the error I get from arXiv after compiling: Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 

l.132 \begin
{document}
? 
! Emergency stop.

Comment: Thanks for these extra pieces of information. I'm not doubting that you're getting an error message, by the way. The issue is that without an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that gives rise to the problem, it's very unlikely that someone will manage to come up with a correct diagnosis, let alone a cure.

Comment: I noticed this issue is often raised by arXiv seemingly without reasons, but you can ignore it, if there are no other errors compilation will succeed.  If it fails, probably there are other errors that should be actually addressed.