# bibliography from in document to .bib/.bbl file?

Tags: bibliographies

I have a tex file that has its biblography at the bottom of the article, but ArXiv does not like that and demands a bbl file. Is there an easy way to copy paste the bibitem objects into one of these files without having to completely change the format?

e.g. `\bibitem[Landau et al.(1992)]{1992A&A...259..696L} Landau, R., Grasdalen, G., \& Sloan, G.~C.\ 1992, \aap, 259, 696`

Comment: Mhhh, I always thought the arXiv liked it when the bibliography was added directly at the end with `thebibliography`. That is standard procedure and avoids all the `.bbl` malarkey that is normally necessary to upload to the arXiv (since they don't run BibTeX/process `.bib` files). Can you show us what your document looks like and what exactly the arXiv complains about?

Comment: The first error is `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.` and has little to do with citations. (See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329461/35864). Note also that currently your `.bbl` file is missing the `\begin{thebibliography}{9}...\end{thebibliography}`. There are also errors about the figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you created the `thebibliography` environment by hand. If this assumption is correct, and assuming further that your main tex file is called `main.tex`, you should

- copy all material in `main.tex` between `\begin{thebibliography}{}` and `\end{thebibliography}` into a file called `main.bbl`. (You may have to create this file from scratch; and
- replace the copied material in the main tex file with the single instruction

  ```
  \input{main.bbl}
  ```

where `main` should correspond to the filename of your main tex file.

If you then rerun LaTeX on your main tex file, the output should be exactly the same.